# Capture what user is typing when the internet is switched on in Android

Tags: android, service

I am trying to create a key-logger sort of an application for parents to use on their kids phones when the internet is on. Mostly chatting and internet surfing. I know there are apps for that, but i need to learn and build one by my self. I prepared a code with my little knowledge as far as i could. But i'm not sure if i can use it to capture all the keyboard typing events by running in background.

**Receiver class**

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        boolean isConnected = wifi != null && wifi.isConnectedOrConnecting()
                || mobile != null && mobile.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        if (isConnected) {
            Log.d("Network Available ", "Yes");
            Intent i = new Intent(context, services.class);
            context.startService(i);
        } else {
            Log.d("Network Available ", "NO");
        }

    }
```

**Service Class**

```
public class services extends Service{

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.i("worked", "A");
    }

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    boolean doKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent msg) {
        switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A:
            Log.i("Pressed : ", "A");
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_B:
            Log.i("Pressed : ", "B");
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_C:
            Log.i("Pressed : ", "C");
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_D:
            Log.i("Pressed : ", "D");
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_E:
            Log.i("Pressed : ", "E");
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_F:
            Log.i("Pressed : ", "F");
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_G:
            Log.i("Pressed : ", "G");
            break;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_H:
            Log.i("Pressed : ", "H");
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: that is security bridge so it is not possible to capture keyboard events of other applications.

Comment: So how does the keyloggers in google play works?

Comment: Its possible. Apparently those apps in google play runs an unkillable service that listens to all Key Events and store those words or letters in sqlite database.

Comment: so.............. @icaneatclouds how can i build something like that?